# esp32 micropython littlefs

Tags: filesystems, esp32, micropython

Using a Expressif dev-board and standard micropython.bin I was able to create a littlefs2 partition, mount it and write data into a file:

```
 # ESP8266 and ESP32
import os
os.umount('/')
os.VfsLfs2.mkfs(bdev)
os.mount(bdev, '/'))

with open("myfile.txt", "a") as f:
  f.write("myData")
```

Once I have done this os.listdir() will show the myfile.txt file but I can't see a way to update my code on the ESP anymore. 
I assume I need to get rid of the littlefs2 file system first but could not find an example for that. 
The only way I found for changing my code was erasing all flash, load a new copy of micropython.bin and then flash my code modules again onto the chip - which is kind of a long process for every change in my code?
 Any shorter/faster way to update my code files on the ESP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A - Revert to fat

if reformat with vfsFat is close enough to 'getting rid of' you can do the following:

```py
import os
os.umount('/')
os.VfsFat.mkfs(bdev)
os.mount(bdev, '/')

import _boot
```

this should re-format the flash as fat, and re-init using the post_flash `_boot` module

### B- Use an IDE to write code for/to the MCU

Assuming you also have a serialport ( or telnet) connection to your MCU another approach is to use an IDE ( [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) + [Pymakr](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pycom.Pymakr) works for sure, or likely [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) works as well)  to connect to your MCU.
Pymakr will happily upload / download files from whatever filesystem you are using, as long as the files are not TOO HUGE

### C - use a cmdline tool to download files from your MCU

there are a few tools for this

- [rshell](https://github.com/dhylands/rshell#rshell)
  advantage: can download complete folders, but may have same issues on windows
- [pyboard.py](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/pyboard.py.html)
  simple to use for single file up/download not for more complex operations. Do NOT use the stale version from PyPi
- [mpremote](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/mpremote.html)
  newest tool with more functionality , not supported against older firmware versions.